# Apply a user defined function to a list of data frames

Tags: r, list, loops, lapply, data-cleaning

I have a series of data frames structured similarly to this:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c('notes','year',1995:2005), y = c(NA,'value',11:21))  
df2 <- data.frame(x = c('notes','year',1995:2005), y = c(NA,'value',50:60))
```

In order to clean them I wrote a user defined function with a set of cleaning steps:

```
clean <- function(df){
  colnames(df) <- df[2,]
  df <- df[grep('^[0-9]{4}', df$year),]
  return(df)
}
```

I'd now like to put my data frames in a list:

```
df_list <- list(df,df2)
```

and clean them all at once. I tried

```
lapply(df_list, clean)
```

and

```
for(df in df_list){
  clean(df)
}
```

But with both methods I get the error:

```
Error in df[2, ] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

What's causing this error and how can I fix it? Is my approach to this problem wrong?

Comment: You don't have a column `df$year`. Your data creation code is wrong, see what is created with that code and correct it, please.

Comment: Within the data cleaning function the column names are set to the second row in the data frame. The second row contains the strings "year" and "value".

The function works properly when you pass a single df to the function, but gets an error when I try to loop through it or apply it to a list.

Comment: Don't you need a comma in `df <- df[grep('^[0-9]{4}', df$year),]`?

Comment: You're right, typo on my end. Unfortunately not the cause of the issue though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close, but there is one problem in code.  Since you have text in your dataframe's columns, the columns are created as factors and not characters.  Thus your column naming does not provide the expected result.

```
#need to specify strings to factors as false
df <- data.frame(x = c('notes','year',1995:2005), y = c(NA,'value',11:21), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)  
df2 <- data.frame(x = c('notes','year',1995:2005), y = c(NA,'value',50:60), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

clean <- function(df){
  colnames(df) <- df[2,]
  #need to specify the column to select the rows
  df <- df[grep('^[0-9]{4}', df$year),]

  #convert the columns to numeric values
    df[, 1:ncol(df)] <- apply(df[, 1:ncol(df)], 2, as.numeric)

  return(df)
}

df_list <- list(df,df2)
lapply(df_list, clean)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! This works on my example data set but I seem to have trouble applying it to my actual data. What I think is causing the problem:

There are about 20 columns rather than 2, is there an elegant way to convert all to numerics rather than calling each column and using the as.numeric() function? I tried adding 
`apply(df,2,as.numeric)` 
to the function but it doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: @Oct, See the edit above, you need to specify the columns which needs to be converted in the apply statement and in the return.  For all columns: `df[, 1:ncol(df)] `