# Trying to find the number of diagonals of 1 in each 3x3 tile in multiple binary matrice list

Tags: r, list, diagonal

I am trying to find the count of diagonal 1s in each 3x3 tile e.g.

```
0 0 1         1 0 0           1 1 1         0 1 1
0 1 0         0 1 0           1 1 1         0 1 0
1 0 0    or   0 0 1     or    1 1 1    or   1 0 0
```

just for example where it doesn't matter about the other values in the 3x3 tile just the diagonals. By diagonals I mean the main diagonals as well as the reverse main diagonals. **For example the following matrix would output 3 diagonals,**

```
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I am reading in a list of matrices...

```
set.seed(1234)
mat1 <- matrix(sample(c(0,1), 225, prob=c(0.8,0.2), replace=TRUE), nrow = 15)

set.seed(99)
mat2 <- matrix(sample(c(0,1), 225, prob=c(0.8,0.2), replace=TRUE), nrow = 15)

set.seed(123)
mat3 <- matrix(sample(c(0,1), 225, prob=c(0.8,0.2), replace=TRUE), nrow = 15)


mat_list <- list(mat1, mat2, mat3)
```

Any suggestions as to how this could be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to find the number of diagonals of 1 in each 3x3 tile in a 15x15 binary matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58580834/trying-to-find-the-number-of-diagonals-of-1-in-each-3x3-tile-in-a-15x15-binary-m)

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I am looking for main diagonals and reverse main diagonals. I have included an example in my question.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I have provided expected output for the example provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `m` is as shown in the Note at the end (and in particular the entries are double and not integer), the positions are at fixed distances so we can use `rollapply` with the function `identical`.

```
library(zoo)

num_diags <- function(m) {
  nr <- nrow(m)
  sum(rollapply(c(m), list(c(0, nr+1, 2*nr+2)), identical, c(1, 1, 1))) +
    sum(rollapply(c(m), list(c(0, nr-1, 2*nr-2)), identical, c(1, 1, 1)))
}

num_diags(m)
## 3
```

To apply this to a list of matrices:

```
sapply(mat_list, num_diags)
```

### Note

```
m <- structure(c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(8L, 
15L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, NULL))
```

Comment: Can this be used with the list though @G.Grothendieck? I have tried this and I get `Error in zoo(data) : “x” : attempt to define invalid zoo object`. I also have more than 3 matrices in my list I just included 3 examples for this question.

Comment: Have added that.